# mapping cell formatting from one sheet to another with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm recursively writing some text to a sheet. In another sheet, I have all those text values in a column of another sheet, where the column to the right contains the respective rename and formatting of the text values I have. This is an example:
https://ethercalc.org/46ky7t3kbik1

How can I reference this "Formatting" sheet, to get the value and formatting of the cell to the right of every cell I can map to?

Comment: Kind of hard to understand the question.. can you provide an example/screenshots, Also, have you tried anything so far that hasn't worked?

Comment: So I'm recursively acquiring some text value, for example "alpha", which I want to write to an output sheet. In the formatting sheet in the link, I have these text values in the second column labled "Child". To the right of this column, I have a column labled "Name", which has an updated text value as well as formatting which I want to the output sheet, instead of just "alpha". For example, I would be writine **ALPH** instead of alpha.

Comment: How are the formatting and updated name separated in the cell? Also what do you mean by formatting? Could you give a specific example?

Comment: The formatting and updated name are in the same column, its a preset color/boldness set in Excel on the updated name in the column so I'd have to fetch it somehow and I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So not sure about the recursive part but this is how you can reference the `sheets/cells` and search for words that are **bold** and **colored**.

```
Function returnFontColor(targetString As String) As Integer

    Dim formatSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim counter As Integer

    returnFontColor = 0

    Set formatSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("insert format sheet name")

    With formatSheet

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        For row = 2 To lastRow
            If Lcase(CStr(.Range("B" & row).Value)) = Lcase(CStr(targetString)) Then
                For counter = 1 To Len(.Range("C" & row).Value)
                    If .Range("C" & row).Characters(Start:=counter, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex <> 0 Then

                        returnFontColor = .Range("C" & row).Characters(Start:=counter, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex
                        GoTo Exiter
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
Exiter:

End Function
```

Comment: I think I miscommunicated the problem. From the VBA code, I don't know color I'm looking for. I simply have a text value that I want to map to a cell, which will have some color (lets ignore bold). I want to grab this color with my function, then simply have the function return it (maybe in the form of RGB values?) and use what the function returns when writing to cells in my predefined code.

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois updated the answer to return a ColorIndex of the first character in cell thats not black (ColorIndex = 0). You can pass a searchable string like "alpha" to function and it will look for it in "Child" column (B). This link explains colorindexes of fonts/cells: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois assuming your searching for font color and not cell fill color